# IDA PRO "try{" comment

Tags: ida

2 related questions:
I noticed that in some of the blocks in the graph there are more branches that I would expect.
These are not jump tables yes I see, e.g. 3 possible branches.
How come?
The 2nd issues, which may be related is what does the “try{“ comment mean? 
[image]

or this:
[image]

Comment: these are due to exception handling.

Comment: Only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: @user202729 Those are two side-effects of the same behavior. Those two questions are well to be together.

Answer (score 1):

IDA is able to parse exception handling tables at least for Visual C++. It annotates the code blocks referenced in the table with the try comments, and also annotates the exception handling code with a comment like "exception handler for try block at XXX". I tend to not use graph view, so I can only guess that the extra edges in the flow graph point from the try block to exception handling blocks.